# Check for <Confiugre> event without bind

Tags: python, tkinter

Take this code;

```
import tkinter as tk

def root_changed(event):
   print(5)

root = tk.Tk() 
root.bind("<Configure>",root_changed)
root.mainloop()
```

When "<Configure>" is given by the tkinter app, 5 is printed.

I want to utilize this to do something without binding it

```
import tkinter as tk

def root_changed(event):
   print(5)

root = tk.Tk() 

wait until root."<Configure>" is called
root_changed()

root.mainloop()
```

The code would be implemented here:

```
   def font_update_recursion():
      root.unbind("<Configure>")
      process = []
      for page in (root.home_page, root.array_page, root.search_page, root.sort_page):
         root.update()
         temp_thread = threading.Thread(target = page.change_font_size)
         process.append(temp_thread)

      for i in process:
            i.start()
            #print(process)

      for i in process:
            i.join()
      if len(root.children) != 0:
         root.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: threading.Thread(target= font_update_recursion).start())
```

This is my first time doing recursion, so if you see any problems, please let me know. This work for recursion, but I was wondering if there was a general case, where bind and unbind is not possible.

Comment: There is no way to react to an event without using `bind`.

Comment: Why are you using threads simply to change a font size? That seems like an incredibly complex solution to a simple problem.

Comment: Its because the application was lagging, so I came up with the most stupid idea, to do threading. Not like it helped.